# How to filter a table using awk

Tags: awk, filter, table

I was wondering how to filter a table with several columns based on a specific value in each of the columns of interest.

I have this example here:

```
    Chr1    16644   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16645   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16646   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16647   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16648   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16649   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16650   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16651   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16782   0       0       0       0
    Chr1    16783   0       0       0       0
    Chr1    16784   0       0       0       0
    Chr1    16785   0       0       0       0
    Chr1    16786   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16787   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16788   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16789   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16790   0       0       1       1
```

And I would like to remove all the rows containing a zero in all of the columns 3,4,5,6.

I have tried it as such

```
cat STARsamples_read_depth.txt | awk '$3 != 0 && $4 != 0&& $5 != 0 && $6 != 0' | less
```

But it removes also the rows where only some of these columns have a zero, not in all four!

Is there a way to do it?

thanks

Assa

Comment: Try `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Devon mentioned in the comments: Use `||` instead of `&&`.

The reason is that you want show lines where at least **one** of the columns 3,4,5,6 is different then zero.

Here's another way to understand it. You're trying to remove lines where those columns are all zeros. Let's begin with the other way around: **print** all the lines where all those columns are 0. This is easy:

```
awk '$3 == 0 && $4 == 0 && $5 == 0 && $6 == 0'
```

Now you want to **invert** this statement: Show all the lines that **don't** match the condition above. So you just negate the statement.

```
awk '(!($3 == 0 && $4 == 0 && $5 == 0 && $6 == 0))'
```

The command above will also fulfill your requirement, by the way.

Anyway, according to [logical negation rules](https://www.math.toronto.edu/preparing-for-calculus/3_logic/we_3_negation.html), the negation of the statement **"A *and* B"** is **"not A *or* not B"**. So to negate this statement:

```
$3 == 0 && $4 == 0 && $5 == 0 && $6 == 0
```

You need to negate each expression, and transform all the **"and"** operators to **"or"**.

```
$3 != 0 || $4 != 0 || $5 != 0 || $6 != 0
```

Now you can better understand why your command didn't work. The negation of the statement you used would be:

```
$3 == 0 || $4 == 0 || $5 == 0 || $6 == 0
```

Which means it would remove all the lines where at least **one** of the columns (and not all) is zero.

Answer (score 6):

Using any awk you can just test if the concatenation of the fields you're interested in results in a non-zero number:

```
$ awk '($3$4$5$6)+0' file
    Chr1    16644   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16645   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16646   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16647   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16648   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16649   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16650   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16651   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16786   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16787   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16788   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16789   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16790   0       0       1       1
```

or if you want to test each field individually for some reason then:

```
$ awk '{for (i=3; i<=6; i++) if ($i != 0) { print; next } }' file
    Chr1    16644   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16645   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16646   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16647   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16648   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16649   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16650   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16651   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16786   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16787   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16788   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16789   0       0       1       1
    Chr1    16790   0       0       1       1
```

If your input might not be whole numbers as shown in the question (see the comments) then use the 2nd script above or you could make it a string instead of numeric comparison on the concatenation:

```
awk '($3$4$5$6) != "0000"' file
```

Comment: Why `$3$4$5$6` alone is not taken as zero in `awk`?

Comment: Because it's doing string concatenation so the type of the result is "string" rather than "numeric" so we need to add `0` to convert it to a number. As a string comparison `00000` is not null and so using that in a comparison would be true rather than false.

Comment: You first method would work only if columns 3-6 are all numbers.  If any of those columns is text, or even a negative number or a fraction, it would fail printing the line.

Comment: @aviro the values in the target fields as shown by the OP  are whole numbers (actually just 0 or 1), there's no reason to complicate a script trying to handle values that we have no reason to think exist and don't have any requirements for but if the OP does want to test each field individually that could be one reason to use the second script in my answer.

Comment: You're probably right, but it's still based on assumptions. You should at least add a disclaimer, so that if someone else that has a similar problem stumbles upon this answer, he'd be aware of the constraints.

Comment: @aviro I added an alternative for the case where the input isn't whole numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '!/(\s+0){4}$/' file
Or
$ awk '!/([[:space:]]+0){4}$/' file
```

The second command requires POSIX awk.

Removing records containing all the fields i.e. `$3`, `$4`, `$5` and `$6` have zero. As suggested by @EdMorton

```
$ awk '{ x=4;for(i=3;i<=6;i++) if ($i==0) {x--;} }x' file
```

Removing records containing if even one of the fields i.e. `$3`, `$4`, `$5` and `$6` have zero.

```
$ awk '{ x=1;for(i=3;i<=6;i++) if ($i==0) {x=0;break;} }x'
```

The for loop `(i=3;i<=6;i++)` is because filtering of fields 3,4,5,6.